# php automated sitemap for a free classified ads website

Tags: php, sitemap

i am looking for a good way to automaticly create/update sitemp for my website [www.indexagahi.com](http://www.indexagahi.com) 
its a free classified ads site , i want to rebuild or update sitemap.xml whenever an ads has been added .
whats your idea ? is it possible .

Comment: PS... I see you are new here, you should vote up helpful answers and accept the most helpful answer. To vote up you just press the upward triangle that is next to the answer and to accept an answer you press the check mark next to it.

Comment: thanks josh i am looking for a php sulotion ,somthing like a script

Answer (score 1):

I wouldnt do it anytime an ad is added, if you have a large number of users it would constantly be updating. Also if you try doing it at the same time a user submits an ad then they will have a long wait while the script runs. I would setup a cron job to do it every 30 or 60 mins. This will prevent it from constantly running and it will keep the user from having long waits for an ad to submit.

Comment: I added a more of an explanation. Do you still need more?

Comment: how does it work ? more about "cron job" please;any source?ways?